# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error from rendering a page of another conroller

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4. I would like to ask if how can I fix this error.

I am rendering another view from another controller. I have a two controllers, Denomination and DenominationPeriod, with each different models. What I want is, render the views of my DenominationPeriod. But I get this error when I try to run the program. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is the renderpage code in my Denomination view.

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/DenominationPeriod/Index.cshtml");
```

It says that the error is from /Views/DenominationPeriod/Index.cshtml

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What's in /Views/DenominationPeriod/Index.cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you get an error becuase `@RenderPage` uses the same model for the view as the current one. You have mentioned that models are different so please use `@Html.RenderPartial` or `@Html.RenderAction` and pass required model with arguments.

Comment: Can you state an example? Thanks

Comment: For good example please share your DenominationPeriod and Denomination models code. But there should be something like that  @Html.RenderAction("Index", "DenominationPeriod", new DenominationPeriodMode()); here I have user constructor of DenominationPeriodModel but you may what to pass there object with some data. As for render partial you may use: @{Html.RenderPartial("DenominationPeriodView", new DenominationPeriodMode());} but in this case you will also have to refactor your ~/Views/DenominationPeriod/Index.cshtml to partial view.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to use Html.RenderAction instead?

Comment: Yes. It gives me Compilation Error. :3